# Visual Studio 2015 Server Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2013 under the "Server Explorer" there are nodes for "Management Classes" and "Management Events". When I go to use them in Visual Studio 2015 they are not there. Is there a setting to enable them?

VS 2013

[image: VS 2013 Server Explorer]

VS 2015

[image: VS 2015 Server Explorer]

Comment: Somebody asked the same question about a month later - and found an answer after a few months:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438045/management-classes-missing-in-visual-studio-server-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently they removed it from the IDE.
[MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2193804)