# Management Classes missing in Visual Studio Server Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wmi, server-explorer

I have an issue in Visual Studio 2015 (Professional 64-bit).
In my Server Explorer, I connect to my local host and I can see

- Event Logs
- Message Queues
- Performance Counters
- Services

What I seem to miss here, is Management Classes.
On my previous PC (with VS2013), it was there.
Did I forget to install an option (or extension)?
Or is there an other easy way to generate classes for WMI interaction?

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody misses this functionality? Weird!

Comment: The same situation with Enterprise 2015 Update1.

Comment: On MS site, they say that it is decoupled from the IDE from now on..
Not clear to me why they should do that.
More info: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2193804

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On MS Connect (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2193804) it appears that the functionality is decoupled from the IDE from now on.
They say you can still use the Mgmtclassgen.exe to generate classes.
It is unclear for me why they took the GUI part away from the IDE